# Can we make a labelled parametric plot in which the parameter is integer?

Tags: plotting, complex

Can we make a labelled parametric plot in which the parameters are integers?

I'm just using Wolfram Alpha but could equally use [Mathematica Online](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/online/), and want something like [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/w1ngrpm43z).

I want to plot values of $ x\cdot \exp{(2\pi i\log_{-1/3}x)}$ in the complex plane for integers $x$.

This is only possible in Desmos by sending the complex and real parts to the x and y axes manually.  However, I want to replace the base $2/3$ log with a base $-1/3$ logarithm, and that will either require putting a complex number into the formula or taking a base negative log, neither of which Desmos allows.

I can make a similar parametric plot in Wolfram like [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ParametricPlot%20%5B%7Bu*cos%20(2*pi*log_2%20u),u*sin(2*pi*log_2%20u)%7D,%20%7Bu%20,1,10%7D%5D) but not with labels, and what I really need are the a) integer $u$ only, b) with the base $-1/3$ logarithm and c) labelled.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not concern Mathematica (Wolfram|Alpha is a separate system).

Comment: You could try https://community.wolfram.com

Comment: It is also slightly unclear what, exactly is being asked.

Comment: @Szabolcs does that edit fix it?

Comment: @kirma did you click on the *here* link?

Comment: @kirma I added to the question precisely what I want to plot.

Comment: Please do show what you tried, at the minimum typing up the expressions in Mathematica syntax. I assume you searched the documentation and found `ParametricPlot`. Did you try it? Discrete points can be highlighted with the `Mesh` option that has many examples in the docs.

Comment: How about `ComplexListPlot[Table[Callout[x Exp[2 Pi I Log[-1/3, x]], x], {x, 0, 20}], Joined -> True, Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> PointSize[Large]]` for a start? (`ComplexListPlot` is a new function in v12.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach to plot a connected list of labeled values of a complex-valued equation for integer values of `x`:

```
ComplexListPlot[
 Table[Labeled[x Exp[2 Pi I Log[-1/3, x]], x], {x, 1, 20}], 
 Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.2]]
```

> [image]

A little prettier one with different base of `Log`:

```
ComplexListPlot[
 Table[Labeled[x Exp[2 Pi I Log[3, x]], x], {x, 1, 20}], 
 Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.1]]
```

> [image]

Comment: Top job, thanks.